# Make div go on top of everything

Tags: css, html

I am trying to get a div cover everything on the page when clicking "logout".
At this point, after the session is ended in php, a new page opens up on the website and redirects to the home page, is it possible to do this:

```
<div class="container-popup">
<div class="popup"><span>Logging out...</span></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NW36V/

instead of having a page dedicated for this message?
similar to the logging out message that pops up when logging out of forums

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how do i cover the header, body, footer with a "logging out.." message ? z-index just covers the body

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the z-indexing property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

You could use javascript/JQ to change the index.

Comment: i tried z-indexing but it wouldn't go on top of the header and footer, it will only cover the main content as it is inside <div id="content">, so i am trying to get it to cover everything even though its within that div